# Two Multi-Tiered Checkbox Systems That Do Not Interact With Each Other

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, checkboxlist

I'm trying to create two checkbox systems that do not interact with each other. The problem I'm facing is the master 'select all' box selects all checkboxes in the entire document which ends up selecting all from both forms.

Is there any way to keep all the functionality but keep the forms completely separate?

--- FIRST FORM JAVASCRIPT ---

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('#checkAll').on('click', function () {
    $(document).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
</script>
<script>
$(function () {
  $(".checkall").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
</script>
```

--- SECOND FORM JAVASCRIPT ---

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('#checkAll2').on('click', function () {
    $(document).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
</script>
<script>
$(function () {
  $(".checkall2").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
</script>
```

--- FIRST FORM HTML ---

```
<center><input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="checkAll"></center><br/>             
<div class="row">                   
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <fieldset><div><input type="checkbox" class="checkall"> IT Dept</div><br>
           <div><input type="checkbox"> number 1</div>
           <div><input type="checkbox"> number 2</div>
           <div><input type="checkbox"> number 3</div>
           <div><input type="checkbox"> number 4</div>
        </fieldset>             
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <fieldset><div><input type="checkbox" class="checkall"> Marketing</div><br>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 1</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 2</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 3</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 4</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 5</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 6</div>
        </fieldset> 
    </div>            
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <fieldset><div><input type="checkbox" class="checkall"> Finance</div><br>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 1</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 2</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 3</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 4</div>
        </fieldset> 
    </div>      
</div>
```

--- SECOND FORM HTML ---

```
<center><input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="checkAll2"></center><br/>                
<div class="row">                   
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <fieldset><div><input type="checkbox" class="checkall2"> IT Dept</div><br>
           <div><input type="checkbox"> number 1</div>
           <div><input type="checkbox"> number 2</div>
           <div><input type="checkbox"> number 3</div>
           <div><input type="checkbox"> number 4</div>
        </fieldset>             
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <fieldset><div><input type="checkbox" class="checkall2"> Marketing</div><br>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 1</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 2</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 3</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 4</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 5</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 6</div>
        </fieldset> 
    </div>            
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <fieldset><div><input type="checkbox" class="checkall2"> Finance</div><br>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 1</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 2</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 3</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox"> number 4</div>
        </fieldset> 
     </div>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a container to both forms and then modify your js to check groups separately.

```
$(function () {
  $('.groupCheckAll').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest(".group").find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
$(function () {
  $(".checkall").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

You can check working code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fts9M/1/)

Comment: Perfect. Once again, than you very much Sandeep :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#checkAll, #checkAll2').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().next().next().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pm548/)